# Count occurrences of column value, then input that count into a column, for every row matching aggregated column value:

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to input an aggregated occurrence of a columns' values, into a distinct column in the same `Dataframe`.
I have tried to count the dates column, and input those occurrences into a `dict` value, and the date as a `dict` key.
Then when I try to (boolean) match `df["count"] = df[df[column]==my_dict.keys]` the logic fails on me. I am missing the part where if true, then input my_dict.values().

The `Dataframe`:

```
    Date        Place_code 
14  2020-04-20  282
16  2020-04-23  301
18  2020-04-22  291
20  2020-04-22  422
21  2020-04-22  422
```

Desired `Dataframe` output:

```
    Date        Occurrence    Place_code 
14  2020-04-20  1             282
16  2020-04-23  1             301
18  2020-04-22  3             291
20  2020-04-22  3             422
21  2020-04-22  3             422
```

Also forgive the title, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one liner:

```
df['Occurrence'] = df['Date'].replace(df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Comment: Getting an "unexpected EOF while parsing".

Comment: I had issues some running above answer, but a derivation of it worked: `df['counts'] = df.DATE.map(df.DATE.value_counts())
`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `transform` to return the same length as the original dataframe:

```py
df.assign(Occurence = df.groupby('Date').transform('count'))
# df.assign(Occurence = df.groupby('Date').transform(len))

          Date  Place_code  Occurence
14  2020-04-20         282          1
16  2020-04-23         301          1
18  2020-04-22         291          3
20  2020-04-22         422          3
21  2020-04-22         422          3
```